# nth-child(an+b):hover does not work with CSS animation?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

How to get the rect to change colour when hover?

I tried `#svg rect:nth-child(an+b):hover` syntax and it does not work.

I tried removing the `animation-play-state:paused;` and it does not work.

I tried using `background:` instead of `fill:`and it does not work.

```css
#svg rect {
  --animation-delay: 0.1s;
  animation: ani 1.8s linear infinite var(--animation-delay);
}


#svg rect:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused; /*/ Removing this does not work /*/
  fill:#000; /*/ This is not working /*/
} 


#svg rect:nth-child(2) { --animation-delay: 0.2s; }
#svg rect:nth-child(3) { --animation-delay: 0.3s; }
#svg rect:nth-child(4) { --animation-delay: 0.4s; }
#svg rect:nth-child(5) { --animation-delay: 0.5s; }


#svg rect:nth-child(2):hover { fill:#000; } /*/ This is not working too /*/ 
#svg rect:nth-child(3):hover { background:#fff; } /*/ This is not working too /*/ 

@keyframes ani {
  0% {
    fill: #0057B8;
  }

  20% {
    fill: #F11E4A;
  }

  40% {
    fill: #F8A527;
  }

  60% {
    fill: #266D7F;
  }

  80% {
    fill: #82A;
  }

  100% {
    fill: #0057B8;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="401" height="275" viewBox="0 0 401 275" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect width="401" height="275" fill="white"/>
<rect x="50" y="91" width="57" height="57" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
<rect x="118" y="91" width="57" height="57" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
<rect x="186" y="91" width="57" height="57" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
<rect x="254" y="91" width="57" height="57" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Try `animation: none;` when `:hover`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove the animation and not only paused it to change fill on hover.

Therefore, you must replace

```
#svg rect:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused; 
  fill:#000; 
}
```

by

```
#svg rect:hover {
  animation: none; 
  fill:#000; 
}
```